# What are the design patterns that focus more on increasing the reusability of a software?

Tags: design-patterns

"i'm working on a project to define the three most design patterns that increase reusablity in Java to refactor the softwares using those desing patterns to make them more reusable"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience the patterns that have improved the reusability of my code have been: the Command Pattern, the Template Method, the Factory Method.

These patterns seem simple but they are incredibly powerful in many situation.
I suggest this book also: https://www.amazon.it/Agile-Software-Development-Principles-Practices/dp/0135974445